# Some simple ARMv7 instructions make my bare-metal program (for raspi zero 2 w) crash

Tags: raspberry-pi, armv7, bare-metal, raspberry-pi-zero

i'm new in ARMv7 bare-metal RPi programing (and my english is not very pure).

I follow this tutorial :
https://github.com/cirosantilli/raspberry-pi-bare-metal-blinker.git
as a starting point for building my own RPi "OS" (for learning).
I tested my code on a Raspberry pi zero 2 W (as it was cheap and available).

I changed some lines in main.c for blinking an external LED, and that work fine.

But for some reasons, i tried to add this code:

```
mov r5, #0x5  
mov r6, #0x3
```

just after "_start:" in start.S

And that made my program crash (i.e : my external LED is not blinking anymore).

The most surprising is that I tried to swap these two lines, giving:

```
mov r6, #0x3 
mov r5, #0x5
```

And then, my program run good (i.e : my external LED is blinking).

Thank you for help, have a good day

Comment: That's truly surprising! I don't see how it is possible at all. You have tried it a bunch of times and see that behavior every time, right? And make sure to clean the build. I'd also have a look at disassembly just in case. Other desperate attempts would be to 2) try something similar on QEMU 3) JTAG.

Comment: I don't see anything wrong with adding that 2 lines. Could you provide objdump of your binary ? when 'breaking' lines are present. That might give a clue. But again that's unlikely to be related to addition, that should be something else wrong and that combination just triggers fault